# Why are my en-dashes and em-dashes light gray?

Tags: lyx, punctuation

LyX seems to be generating light gray en-dashes and em-dashes in my PDF preview, when I use `--` and `---`. Why is this happening, and how can I get it to output normal black long dashes?

Edit: I'm on Windows, using:
LyX 2.1.3 (2015-02-06)
Built on Feb  7 2015, 01:01:26
CMake Build

Comment: Please give us an MWE which shows this behaviour. Thank you. The dashes you refer to are much thinner than the `-` hyphen. Do you mean that?

Comment: What do you mean with _lgith gray_? Could you help us to help you adding a MWE of your code? Perhaps your problem has to do with the typography selection you use.

Comment: You could chose another font. E.g. `\usepackage{libertine}` results in more equal looking dashes. The shortest one is still bolder, though, as this seems to be desired.

Comment: I don't really know how to provide a MWE, but if I go to LyX and do File->New, then leave everything at the default, and type up `--a`, when I hit the preview button, Adobe will show a blank page with just a light gray long dash, followed by a normal black lower case a. I've added versioning info to the question.

Comment: @JoãoMendes What happens if you zoom in? What happens if you view the PDF with SummatraPDF (a free PDF reader that seems to work better than Adobe Reader in some dimensions)? What happens if you print the page using the printer? I would not be surprised if this is a viewing issue.

Comment: @scottkosty Sorry it took this long to respond, but I had trouble getting access to a printer. Anyway, it seems you were right. Zooming in and out doesn't change anything, but it does print correctly.

Comment: @JoãoMendes good to know. Glad that print is OK at least. Here on Ubuntu everything looks fine to me.