# Greyed out En dash in resume template

Tags: fonts, color, punctuation, resume

I am using [CS/IT/SWE Resume Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cs-slash-it-slash-swe-resume-template/ncxgzcgknkmf) from Overleaf (and am also a LaTeX noob).

Currently, an en dash `--` shows up as greyed out.  See the below image for what I am seeing:

[image: date range with greyed out en dash]

I don't like this greyed out look, but I do like the overall document's default font.  How can I override this en dash behavior, without changing the global font?

I tried `\textcolor{black}{--}`, but the color wasn't changed.

Looks like a similar question was asked in 2015 with no answers: [Why are my en-dashes and em-dashes light gray?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245571/why-are-my-en-dashes-and-em-dashes-light-gray)

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! Are you really sure that it is grey? The dash is quite thin, so it may just be an effect of rendering on screen. I just ask, because in the preview PDF of this template this dash is just plain black.

Comment: Most likely you're seeing an artifact of your PDF viewer. Have you tried zooming in on the dash to see if the color is still lighter?

Comment: Yes @DonHosek you are correct!  I exported the doc as a PDF and viewed, and the dash is no longer greyed out.  Same fix when zooming in.... it was indeed an artifact of the PDF viewer.  The more you know!

Comment: And thank you as well @JasperHabicht, I appreciate the quick responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Community answer.
- According to the comments, the dash was not grey, instead, this was **caused by the PDF viewer** since the **line width** of the dash is **very thin/small** and only **appears** to be **grey**.